# Error Thrown When Trying to Create Laravel Controller

Tags: php, laravel, terminal

I'm trying to create a controller in Laravel 5.0.16.

When I enter the following artisan command:

```
php artisan make:controller TransactionsController
```

I get this error

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
>   Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Application::getNamespace()

Comment: try to run  composer update command and then try to run controller command

Comment: Thanks! It is all updated. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Delete `vendor/compiled.php` and run `composer update` again

Comment: Now I get the following error:   [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
  Class 'App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider' not found

Comment: try using composer dump-autoload

Comment: Didn't make a difference. Could it be that I'm using an old version of Laravel?

Comment: No, I dont think so. Delete storage/framework/compiled.php then try again.

Comment: That is already removed. Any other ideas? I appreciate the help

Comment: I ran out of ideas. Are you using any lumen package?

Comment: No, I'm not. Thanks for the help. I'll keep trouble shooting it and let you know once I figure it out.

Comment: Did you rename your app using artisN app:name that didnt work maybe? Is the namespace in RouteServiceProvider correct?